# Index related disk availablity issue in GCP VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I am using  Google Cloud Platform (GCP) VM for some Machine learning work. I have 500 GB disk. But as there are millions of files in terms of image datasets used to perform model training, the inodes have exhausted , and as a result of this I am not able to store more images on the disk though the used space is only around 50% of the capacity.

[This GCP document](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/scale) asks to scale the disk which involves more cost. Is there any other way of solving this issue without scaling up the disk in GCP?

Comment: Increasing the disk size will not help. Which file system are you using? My guess is EXT4. I recommend starting over, creating a normal-sized boot disk, and adding another persistent disk. You can then format the new file system with a larger inode table. Look up how to use the `mkfs` or `mke2fs` command. Note: I do not recommend `gcsfuse` in your case. That moves the data somewhere else and does not solve your problem.

Comment: @A.R,  Did your issue get resolved? If not I am happy to assist you further.

Comment: Thanks @Srividya I have created a disk with low inodes to bytes ratio (8192). This has doubled the inodes. But I am not able to test the functioning of the new disk as my VMs are not accessible in Vortex AI workbench due to an issue which is being looked into by IT in my company.

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley Your suggestion has solved my issue. I have created another 500 GB disk with lower value for bytes to inodes ratio (8192). This has resulted in 65536000
 inodes on a 500 GB disk while earlier the same capacity disk had 32768000 inodes.  The following commands did the trick :

 sudo mkfs.ext4 -m 0 -E lazy_itable_init=0,lazy_journal_init=0,discard -i 8192 /dev/disk/by-id/google-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix for the issue is to increase inodes via formatting with parameter -i and lower value for inodes to bytes ratio. The default inode_ratio is 16384. A lesser value can be put for this ratio.

Example:

```
mkfs.ext4 -m 0 -E lazy_itable_init=0,lazy_journal_init=0,discard -i 8192 /dev/disk/by-id/google-data
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing inode exhaustion on your GCP VM due to a large number of files, there are few alternative approaches you can try.

Each file stored on the file share consumes one inode. If the file system runs out of inodes, you are not able to store more files on the file share even if you haven't reached the maximum allocated capacity. The only way to add inodes is by adding capacity. However, reaching the maximum inodes is rare and is only a concern if you need to store many small files.

You can also consider another approach without necessarily scaling the disk and incurring additional charges. Instead of relying on the VM’s local disk, you can consider using Google Cloud Storage buckets to store your image datasets. GCS doesn't have inode limitations and can handle large-scale storage efficiency. You can mount a GCS bucket as a file system on your VM  using **[GCSFUSE](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse#technical-overview)**.

`Cloud Storage Fuse` lets you mount and access Cloud Storage buckets as local file systems and can connect with GKE, Compute Engine VM’s etc. You can refer to the [document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcsfuse-quickstart-mount-bucket) for mounting a cloud storage bucket using gscfuse.

Comment: Thanks Srividya. I will explore the Storage Buckets to check if it can solve my problem